# OSRM-backend returns distance:0

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osrm

So, we have installed OSRM to our server and tested it for http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/40.415225,49.855988;40.356182,49.828279?steps=true. Public demo server returns distance as expected. Unfortunately when requesting route from server distance:0 is returned. I would appreciate any help on topic.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can identify the problem by taking a look at the returned route geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, actually it was kinda technical problem. I should have swapped the order of longitude and altitude. OSRM accepts coordinates with respective order, first longitude and then altitude.

[image]